# Problema con putsmask

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, anaconda

como va? Tengo un dataset de 1gb, que son mas de 110 columnas, y lo intento cargar de la siguiente forma:

`df_horno = pd.read_csv(r"Variables_Horno.csv", sep =";", low_memory = False)`

Luego de cargarlo, me aparece este error:

putmask: mask and data must be the same size

Y antes, me lo tomaba, pero me aparecian todas nands, osea todas las filas y columnas eran nands y no se como solucionarlo. Gracias

Comment: Revisa el separador que tiene el archivo, lo puedes hacer al abrirlo con un editor de textos, también revisa el separador de decimales. También revisa si tienes la última versión de `pandas` ya que [antes había un error](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18368) de `putmask` pero es en una versión bastante antigua

Comment: @HeytalePazguato gracias, revise el separar y todo, el problema era el tipo de encoding, no me lo leia bien pandas sin que lo especifique. Lo tuve que espeficar, era utf-16, y no me lo leia el notepad++. de lo grande que era.